# Remove Non-Updated Text/Object In JSON File With Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

This script updates the code in the json file with the users input but doesn't replace the placeholder text `Screenshot URL X` x is a number (1, 5). I want to remove the placeholder text that hasn't been updated by the script with the user input. It was working before but now it isn't and I can find out why. Any help will be welcomed! Thanks!

Code:

```
# Load the data
file_name = path/to/json/file
with open(file_name) as fh:
    full_data = json.load(fh)

    # Dig into the data to find the screenshots
    screen_shots = full_data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots']

    # Loop over each screen shot, updating each one
    print("Press return/enter to enter another url or press it again with nothing entered to stop asking and continue the script.")
    for number, screen_shot in enumerate(screen_shots):
        new_url = input("Screnshot URL: ").strip()

        if new_url:
            # Updating the data here will also update the 'full_data' object
            # as we are just referencing a part of it, not making copies
            screen_shot.update({"url": new_url, "fullSizeURL": new_url})
        else:
            break

    # Remove all entries which we did not update
    screen_shots = screen_shots[:number]

   # Save the data
    with open(file_name, 'w') as fh:
        json.dump(full_data, fh, indent=4)
```

JSON File:

```
{
  "minVersion": "0.1",
  "headerImage": "Header Image URL",
  "tintColor": "",
  "tabs": [
    {
      "tabname": "Details",
      "views": [
        {
          "title": "Package Name",
          "useBoldText": true,
          "useBottomMargin": false,
          "class": "DepictionSubheaderView"
        },
        {
          "itemCornerRadius": 6,
          "itemSize": "{160, 275.41333333333336}",
          "screenshots": [
            {
              "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
              "url": "Screenshot URL 1",
              "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 1"
            },
            {
              "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
              "url": "Screenshot URL 2",
              "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 2"
            },
            {
              "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
              "url": "Screenshot URL 3",
              "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 3"
            },
            {
              "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
              "url": "Screenshot URL 4",
              "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 4"
            },
            {
              "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
              "url": "Screenshot URL 5",
              "fullSizeURL": "Screenshot URL 5"
            }
          ],
          "class": "DepictionScreenshotsView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": "This is a description.",
          "useSpacing": true,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        },
        {
          "class": "DepictionSeparatorView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Known Issues",
          "class": "DepictionHeaderView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": "None",
          "useSpacing": true,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        },
        {
          "class": "DepictionSeparatorView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Latest Version",
          "class": "DepictionHeaderView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Version",
          "text": "1.2",
          "class": "DepictionTableTextView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Released",
          "text": "1/1/11",
          "class": "DepictionTableTextView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Price",
          "text": "Free",
          "class": "DepictionTableTextView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Developer",
          "text": "Dev",
          "class": "DepictionTableTextView"
        },
        {
          "title": "Contact Support",
          "action": "",
          "class": "DepictionTableButtonView"
        },
        {
          "spacing": 16,
          "class": "DepictionSpacerView"
        },
        {
          "spacing": 20,
          "class": "DepictionSpacerView"
        }
      ],
      "class": "DepictionStackView"
    },
    {
      "tabname": "Changelog",
      "views": [
        {
          "title": "1.2",
          "useBoldText": true,
          "useBottomMargin": true,
          "class": "DepictionSubheaderView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": "\t\n\u2022 Initial Release",
          "useSpacing": false,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        },
        {
          "markdown": "<small style=\"color: #999; margin-top: -8px;\">Released 1/1/11</small>",
          "useRawFormat": true,
          "class": "DepictionMarkdownView"
        }
      ],
      "class": "DepictionStackView"
    }
  ],
  "class": "DepictionTabView"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
import json
file_name = "test.json"
with open(file_name) as fh:
    full_data = json.load(fh)

    # Dig into the data to find the screenshots
    screen_shots = full_data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots']

    # Loop over each screen shot, updating each one
    print("Press return/enter to enter another url or press it again with nothing entered to stop asking and continue the script.")
    for number, screen_shot in enumerate(screen_shots):
        new_url = input("Screnshot URL: ").strip()

        if new_url:
            # Updating the data here will also update the 'full_data' object
            # as we are just referencing a part of it, not making copies
            screen_shot.update({"url": new_url, "fullSizeURL": new_url})
        else:
            break

    # Remove all entries which we did not update
    screen_shots = screen_shots[:number]
    full_data['tabs'][0]['views'][1]['screenshots'] = screen_shots #-> this lines removes the placeholder text that is not updated by the user

    # Save the data
    with open(file_name, 'w') as fh:
        json.dump(full_data, fh, indent=4)
```